# Clang boost oddities

Tags: macos, boost, clang, macports

I am doing a pet project and am using clang++ (specifically MacPorts clang 3.1).  So I decided to switch over to libc++ (to use std::array and such) but I was using boost (specifically asio and regex), so I had to recompile boost using libc++.  I removed boost which was installed in macports and build boost from source and now is installed in /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib.  Ever since then, I cannot compile.  Here are the oddities I am encountering:

When executing:

```
clang++ -g  -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -c main.cpp
```

I get a weird compile error having to do with the move constructor (there's more to this error, but as you can see it is coming from boost):

```
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1952:10: error: overload resolution selected implicitly-deleted copy assignment operator
__r_ = _STD::move(__str.__r_);
     ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1942:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__move_assign' requested here
    __move_assign(__str, true_type());
    ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1961:5: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__move_assign' requested here
__move_assign(__str, integral_constant<bool,
^
/usr/local/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher.hpp:207:16: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::operator=' requested here
        s1 = traits_inst.transform(a, a + 1);
```

However, when I execute (please note the "-I", and it must be in that exact position):

```
clang++ -I -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -g -c main.cpp
```

This compiles (but linking fails later on).  Why is this?  What does -I do without a path?  Must -stdlib= be preceded with -I?

Now the fun part:

Even though, everything compiles now, it won't link.  When executing:

```
clang++ main.o FTPClient.o FTPConnection.o -lboost_system -lboost_regex -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++  -g  -o cli
```

I get the message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initIPKcEENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeESA_SA_", referenced from:
  boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::lookup_collatename(char const*, char const*) const in libboost_regex.a(instances.o)
  boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::lookup_classname_imp(char const*, char const*) const in libboost_regex.a(instances.o)
  boost::re_detail::basic_regex_parser<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::fail(boost::regex_constants::error_type, long, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, long) in libboost_regex.a(instances.o)
  boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::lookup_classname(char const*, char const*) const in libboost_regex.a(instances.o)
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Now I am thinking maybe I a missing some -lboost flag but I am not sure what it is.  What could be the reason for this?

Thanks very much!

EDIT: When looking through the logs of installing boost, I noticed this:

```
..failed clang-darwin.link.dll /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.dylib...
clang-darwin.link.dll /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initIPKcEENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeESA_SA_", referenced from:
  boost::c_regex_traits<char>::transform(char const*, char const*) in c_regex_traits.o
  boost::c_regex_traits<char>::lookup_classname(char const*, char const*) in c_regex_traits.o
  boost::c_regex_traits<char>::lookup_collatename(char const*, char const*) in c_regex_traits.o
  boost::re_detail::RegExData::update() in cregex.o
  boost::RegEx::What(int) const in cregex.o
  boost::re_detail::pred2::operator()(boost::match_results<char const*, std::__1::allocator<boost::sub_match<char const*> > > const&) in cregex.o
  boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::lookup_collatename(char const*, char const*) const in instances.o
  ...
  "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIwNS_11char_traitsIwEENS_9allocatorIwEEE6__initIPKwEENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeESA_SA_", referenced from:
  boost::c_regex_traits<wchar_t>::transform(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*) in wc_regex_traits.o


  boost::c_regex_traits<wchar_t>::lookup_classname(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*) in wc_regex_traits.o
  boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<wchar_t>::lookup_collatename(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*) const in winstances.o
  boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<wchar_t>::lookup_classname_imp(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*) const in winstances.o
  boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<wchar_t>::lookup_classname(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*) const in winstances.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64  
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does this mean boost regex maybe incompatible with -libc++?

EDIT 2:  I tried using std::regex, but I get this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initIPKcEENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeESA_SA_", referenced from:
  std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::regex_traits<char>::__lookup_collatename<char const*>(char const*, char const*, char) const in main.o
  unsigned int std::__1::regex_traits<char>::__lookup_classname<char const*>(char const*, char const*, bool, char) const in main.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: Which OSX are you using if Lion then Xcode includes clang 3.1 if not then /usr/include/c++ is not what you want

Comment: Lion has clang 3.0, so I am using MacPorts.  What should I put in my include path so it doesn't use /usr/include/c++?  Note: I used `-I/opt/local/include` and I get that weird move constructor error from std::regex when compiling.

Comment: If Lion then you do not need macports for clang - use the Xcode one - thenwhat happens

Comment: I had no idea that Xcode had 3.1, but installed the latest Command Line tools and my project compiles now!  (I guess the lib from MacPorts was botched or something)  Thanks very much!

Comment: No the fix is now you are using Xcode's clang - the issue is that your command lines missed the correct include and libs - but much easier just to use Xcode

Comment: Forgive my stupidity, but from what I gather MacPorts clang isn't properly configured out of the box and probably would require symlinks to libs in order for it to work? Also, by off chance do you happen to know if libc++ is compatible with CppUnit?  I have been playing with the globals like CXXFLAGS and LIBS and it doesn't seem to want to link.  Thanks again!

Comment: I think you cannot mix up C++ compilers as their ABIs differ - but I am not certain - I think macports clang is configured correctly but you need to set everything manually in a compile so raise CppUint as another question - the macports port of that will work with Xcode clang

Answer (score 2):

A helpful, but unsatisfactory answer: libc++ contains std::regex, which you can use instead of boost::regex.

Comment: Did you build boost with `clang -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11` ?

Comment: yes I did: `./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags="-I -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++"`, both with and without that "-I" (as a saw that same weird move constructor error while it was building) and using -a a few times.

Comment: Also I did use std::regex, but then I get a linking error (see my edited post). Could my installation of libc++ be screwed up?  Does MacPorts clang even come with libc++ binaries (it obviously comes with the headers as the .cpp files compile)?

Comment: You can look in /usr/lib; look for libc++.dylib.   That's the binary for libc++.

Comment: Note: If you are using pcre (perl compatible regular expressions) then you cannot switch to std::regex.